# Создание БД в ACCESS

Tags: база-данных, access

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, плиз, советом. Решил создать БД в акцессе. Это моя первая база (учусь). Задача передо мной стоит такая. Приезжает авто в техцентр.  Ремонт производят несколько слесарей (связь один ко многим), в свою очередь они производят ремонт нескольких узлов авто. Посмотрите скрин и скажите, плиз, правильно ли я создал таблицы или еще, может, что добавить?

[image]

Comment: @Amangeldi, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1. Может, это и не интересует Вас, но стоимость работ тоже надо как-то учесть (в левой таблице).
2. Вторую справа таблицу рабочих, занятых в наряде, я бы соединил не с нарядом (это братская могила для них: как потом учитывать работу каждого?), а с таблицей второй слева (многое ко многому), развязав эту связь промежуточной таблицей.
3. Не знаю насчет универсальности ремонтников (все-таки, моторист и кузовщик - это разные квалификации).